# What is the Significance of Brahmamuhurtha

Tags: time

I have heard about *Brahmamuhurtha* (Brahma time),  that it is a time where we can do meditation or have good concentration power.

According to [India Times](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/Brahmamuhurta-The-best-time-for-meditation/articleshow/4659848.cms):

> Brahmamuhurta is the morning period between 3.30 a.m. and 5.30 a.m. It is suitable for meditation. After a good night's sleep, the mind is refreshed, calm and serene. There is the preponderance of sattva or purity in the mind at this time, as well as in the atmosphere.

Apart from scientific explanation, Is there any mention about this in Hindu mythology? If so, please explain in detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Brahmamuhurtam* is the time one and a half hour before sunrise, or more precisely is 1 Hr 36 Minutes. i.e. 96 Minutes.

This time is considered apt for religious, yoga and meditative purposes because during this time, the *sattava* *guna* of the environment is highest, after sunrise the *rajas* *guna* overwhelms which is why it's considered good to cook food and perform other daily routines like studying after sun-rise. After sun sets, the *tamas* *gunas* overwhelm and which becomes unsuitable for any religious purposes.

Quoting, [VedantaVision](http://vedantavision.org/content/faq-s/question-10.html)

> A Brahma muhurta has tremendous importance in our lives as it is the time when we can invest our energies in developing our sattvika content. It is a time when the mind is calm, free from distractions of the world and the intellect fresh from a good night’s sleep.

Ashtanga Hridayam (one of the texts in Ayurveda) says,

> The healthy person should get up (from bed) during brahma muhurta, to protect his life. -- Ashtanga Hridayam, vol. I, 2:1

Ref.

1. [Brahmamuhurtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmamuhurtha)
2. [VedantaVision](http://vedantavision.org/content/faq-s/question-10.html)
3. [Banyan Botanicals](http://www.banyanbotanicals.com/library/the-secret/)

Answer (score 0):

Brahma muhurta  is a period one and a half hours before sunrise or more precisely 1Hr 36 Mins before sunrise.  96 Minutes = 2 Muhūrta or 4 Ghaṭīkā,and each Muhurta lasting for 48 minutes. Literally meaning "The Creator's Hour", it is traditionally the last phase or muhurta of the night and is considered an auspicious time for all practices of yoga and most appropriate for meditation, worship or any other religious practice.

Comment: Don't post spam link and also provide source of your information.